# Custom dimension pageviews change by simply adding the page title as second dimension?

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

I set up a Google analytics custom dimension so that I could track categories (i.e. what are my top X posts in a given category).

I checked the debug logs and the data seems to be sending properly on all posts.  I'm also receiving the category data on the backend but I'm noticing something odd.

If I view all PAGEVIEWS for a given category (ex. NEWS) I'm looking at 300.  But if I add PAGETITLE as a secondary dimension (so I can see which posts that 300 comprise) the total swells to 400.  How is that possible?

Also, in that view say given NEWS posts shows 30 PAGEVIEWS.  If I simply pull up the stock Site Content report, that same posts will show considerably more PAGEVIEWS.  Again, I'm not sure how I'm getting this disparity.   Any ideas?

My custom dimension is set to HIT scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... the problem here seems to be the fact that all CUSTOM REPORTS - through which the DASHBOARD seems to draw the data - are SAMPLED.  So, for a PAGEVIEW report that relies on the aggregate, you'll only see a fragment of the data.

This became obviously clear when I had the exact report I wanted under GA standard reports in Page Content, and then clicked Add to Dashboard only to see the numbers immediately shrink.

Live and learn.